# Using a form in PHP, I am trying to return an SQL value dependant on an entered SQL value?

Tags: php, mysql

My DB looks like this

> **paynumber fullname    linemanager**
>  12345     John Smith  Jack Jones
>  12346     Joe Bloggs  Andy Smith

I want it so if you enter `12345` into a textfield it will return John Smith in the same text field

I've tried so many mysql_queries I don't know which one to post!

I'm not looking for full code, as I'm not bad at that, but please point me in the right direction!

Cheers!

```
    <?php


    $mysql_host = "host"; 
    $mysql_username = "user"; 
    $mysql_password = "pass"; 
    $link = mysql_connect("$mysql_host", "$mysql_username", "$mysql_password");
    mysql_select_db("dbname",$link); 

    $pay_number=intval($_POST["pay_number"]);
    $result = mysql_query($link,"SELECT fullname from officers where paynumber=$pay_number");

    echo $result;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fullname from myTable where paynumber=12345
```

What's so tough about it? Then you can display it anywhere you like. Can add a little bit of AJAX to grab the result and show in the same field.

**EDIT:**

Lets say your field  on your HTML form was named `pay_number` and form method was `POST`

Then in your PHP processing code you could do

```
$pay_number=intval($_POST["pay_number"]);
$query="SELECT fullname from myTable where paynumber=$pay_number";
```

Comment: This is wicked, but a further question: how do I echo the return of fullname?

Comment: Please post this code in question so we can see it formatted.

Comment: Sorry, my first question on this site so I'm not sure how to post code properly!